# How to use a Flask Api with Flutter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to make a simple app with `flutter` and using data from a `python` script as flask `restful-api`. I made my script and I can get the results with this way: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/query?username=username1` as `json` formatted.
The thing I am trying to do exactly is that; when my app started to work a pop-up window will ask `username`, after `username` is entered it will go to the main widget of the app and that widget will take data from `json` in my `api` page.
So for doing this should I use an online `api` or web server if there is one for `python`? I looked up the google app engine, but I couldn't even upload my script there. So what's the simpliest way to link my restful-api to my `flutter` app(and finally `apk` file) as able to work on any phone? My script code is below, `flutter` side is still in progress till I figured out how can I work with an `api` by `python` in `flutter`..

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import random
import imdb
from trakt.users import User

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def query():
    username = request.args['username']
    moviesDB = imdb.IMDb()
    my = User(str(username))
    myline = str(random.choice(my.watchlist_movies))[9:1000]
    print(myline)
    movies = moviesDB.search_movie(str(myline))
    id = movies[0].getID()
    movie = moviesDB.get_movie(id)
    title = movie['title']
    year = str(movie["year"])
    rating = str(movie["rating"])
    runtime = ' '.join(map(str, movie["runtimes"]))
    directStr = ' '.join(map(str, movie["directors"]))
    writerStr = ', '.join(map(str, movie["writers"]))
    actors = ', '.join(map(str, movie["cast"]))
    summary = movie["plot outline"]
    genre = ', '.join(map(str, movie["genres"]))
    posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]

    return jsonify(movietitle=title,
                   movieyear=year, movierating=rating, moviegenres=genre, movieruntime=runtime,
                   moviedirectors=directStr,
                   moviewriters=writerStr,
                   moviecast=actors,
                   movieplotline=summary,
                   movieposterurl=posterurl)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: if you use `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` then all devices in your local network can access it using your computer's local IP - like `192.168.0.1`. You can check local IP with `ipconfig` on Windows or `ifconfig` on Linux/Mac. And if routes (yours and Internet Provider) forwarding some port to your local computer (ie. port 80) then using `app(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)` you could access it from internet using external IP - which you can check with many pages on Internet.

Comment: you can try to [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to use your local computer as server.

Comment: thanks, i will try that because this could be a suitable solution for my current project which is a very simple app but for long term I think I need to try an online server to handle more request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the question is really where should you host your python api? If that is the case then the answer is wherever you decide heh. If you are looking for free solutions you can take a look at these two: [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) and [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com). Both are free but for Heroku a valid credit card must be provided to get full up-time. That being said if your app is going to generate a decent amount of traffic then I strongly suggest you either rent a VPS or a Dedicated server running Linux (many... many hosting providers out there).

Comment: thanks for suggestions, i will try both. actually i tried pythonanywhere for my another project but it wasn't a flask or api related one, but i looked it now it make sense to use for that so I can give a try for an api server too.